# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting chemistry research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3546).

Answer (score 19):

[image: Visit our meta site!]

Answer (score 18):

[image: The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Comment: Shamelessly stolen from [last year](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3083)

Comment: I "borrowed" the high-resolution version from Math.SE

Answer (score 15):

[image: AIST Spectral Database for Organic Compounds]

Comment: Straight-up repost from [last year](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3082/11367). Considering switching to an NMR for Jan's benefit. :-) Open to suggestions as to which chemical's spectrum to use.

Comment: A ¹H-NMR of the Buckminsterfullerene would be quite tidy :D

Comment: Replaced the naphthalene IR spectrum with the $^{13}\ce{C}$ NMR for [orthocresol](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/direct_frame_disp.cgi?sdbsno=1368).

Comment: I can’t express my love in enough upvotes. Shame I can’t bounty on meta <3

Answer (score 11):

[image: NIST CompChem Comparison & Benchmark Database]

Comment: Straight-up repost from [last year](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3172/11367).

Comment: Every since they redid their site I don't want to vote for it...

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon ? What did they change? It

Comment: They didn't use to have those terrible JavaScript menus at the top, they were just static links. Been at least a year.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon Ahhh, I hadn't used it extensively enough to even notice. Yeah, those are kind of annoying.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Current Chemistry Stack Exchange bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/chemistry.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: Reposting from 2016

Comment: not working anymore for all the sites

Comment: @AnkitSharma Switching from `http` to `https` appears to fix.

Comment: @hBy2Py it was fixed long long back https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/community-promotion-ads-2017#comment10601_2618

Comment: @AnkitSharma Ahh, well, this one was still broken until just now. :-)

Answer (score 10):

[image: Avogadro - the open molecular editor]

Comment: Reposting from 2016

Answer (score 9):

[image: Let's do the bounty dance! Enter your favourite question today!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score 8):

[image: Retraction Watch]

Comment: Reposting from 2016

Answer (score 8):

[image: archive.org - the public library of the internet]

Comment: Shamelessly stolen from [physics.se](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9573/104362), all credit goes to [Emilio Pisanty](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/1327/e-p).

Comment: The guy is a community ads *machine*.

Comment: @hBy2Py Thanks =D.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Earth Science on Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Click here to learn how to format chemical compounds and reaction mechanisms]

Answer (score 5):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

Comment: Without clicking on the link, I assume that CS means computer science, but it wasn't really obvious to me at first glance. Idk, maybe it's obvious enough to other people.

Comment: @orthocresol Well, the background C++ codes can certainly make up for what the ad's about.

Comment: Counter Strike and Creative Suite were my first associations. Maybe I'm not a chemist [enough].

Answer (score 4):

[image: Click here if you want to post a community ad]

Comment: I designed this ad after seeing @EmilioPisanty's ad on physics meta.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Science Educators]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Digital Library of Mathematical Functions]

Comment: Crosspost from [entry at Physics.SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9566/69087), posted by [Emilio Pisanty](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/users/8563/emilio-pisanty).

Comment: Yes! They hate it, they really hate it! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Materilas Project]

Comment: What is this?$%$

Comment: @Jan a super project! :-) Click to discover!

Comment: Downvoted for not willing to provide information.

Comment: @Jan Harnessing the power of supercomputing and state of the art electronic structure methods, the Materials Project provides open web-based access to computed information on known and predicted materials as well as powerful analysis tools to inspire and design novel materials.

Comment: Hi @jan nobody writes anything about the project on this page, you just click on the tumbnail and see the description on the about page of the project. Who else can describe better the project?  I don't see any link about the goodness of a project with the fact that I "don't want to provide information".  I don't see the need of a further repetition of content.  Please, read https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote to understand how to vote correctly.

Comment: LOL! Thanks for pointing me to the help centre, I wonder how I got my $\pu{36 krep}$ without it. No, in all seriousness: these are ads. If they appear on the site (i.e. pass the magical threshold of six votes) they should speak for themselves. Typically by [explaining what’s going on](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3574) or by [having a descriptive title](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3555). If I can’t tell what your ad is about, I want to stop it from getting on the site.  Most notably, the information should be *before* the first click.

Comment: @GM Maybe you could move the entire stuff (diagram+heading+text) just a few pixels up so that the top and bottom paddings are equal? Nice addition though!

Answer (score -2):

[image: March supporting government policy informed by science]

Comment: If you see this as political (which i think is debatable),  and don't think it belongs here, it has been proposed also for Academia.SE, where it falls within the site's mandate much more clearly. If you are a member there, that post is [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/3692/69922).

Answer (score -3):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]