# Is it acceptable to use personally-made software in the community promotion ads?

Tags: discussion

The [2017 community promotion ads](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/community-promotion-ads-2017) thread tells us that these kinds of ads would qualify:

> - the site's twitter account
> - interesting chemistry research sites
> - useful resources for practitioner and student alike
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

(My laboratory group and) I have been developing some useful chemistry software for a while now. In particular, molecular dynamics and monte carlo modeling software: https://github.com/khavernathy/mcmd , https://github.com/mpmccode/mpmc

Is it a jump to publicize our lab's code (cited some dozens of times) via the Chemistry.SE ads? i.e. if I want to share an ad, should I restrict myself to a more ubiquitous tool/software (like LAMMPS, cited thousands of times)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always propose a community ad as per the guidelines outlined in the thread you linked and cited from. It is up to the community whether they deem your ad good or bad; if it gets a net score of six, it will be displayed on the main site.

Contrary to the effects of voting on the main site, upvotes or downvotes on meta do not cause any reputation changes at all, so you have nothing to lose. Or, as I like saying: You’ve got a no, but you have the chance of getting a yes.

I do think that compchem software would, in general, fall under the final one of the bullet points. However, I will urge you to choose a self-explaining ad and/or describe the project(s) briefly in the comment below your answer so that we all have a better idea of what you want to promote.

Comment: I second that, but would like to give an example: [Geoff Hutchison's Avogadro](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3575/4945) only recently made the cut (Sept. 12). It took more than half a year to reach the threshold. The question is if it is worth your while creating the ad. [See some statistics here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3546).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - it's possible that the slow up-vote for Avogadro was partly due to running ads previously. I sense the community likes to see new resources and ads. :-)