# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting chemistry research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4097).

Comment: Could we do - http://molecule-viewer.com/ - next year?

Answer (score 11):

[image: Current Chemistry Stack Exchange bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/chemistry.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: This image went kerplooie, Geoff

Comment: This still looks okay for me, but it's a tricky thing - half supported Stack Exchange but run by a different contributor.

Comment: Oh, huh - now it loaded fine. Makes sense that it might flake out occasionally, then, running across platforms. Didn't realize.

Answer (score 10):

[image: The Periodic Table. Come chat with us!]

Comment: [Repost from last year.](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3548/4945) Sometimes I think it could use some more attention still...

Answer (score 10):

[image: Writing.SE welcomes questions about academic, scientific, and technical writing]

Comment: Hello.  I hope you don't mind the intrusion.  I'm a moderator on Writing, where academic/scientific writing is on-topic (we're not just for fiction).  Your community seems to have a strong ad culture, so I hope you will consider our submission.  (Writing is still in beta and thus can't host ads in return, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 9):

[image: NIST CompChem Comparison & Benchmark Database]

Comment: No need to change up a good thing (depending on who you talk to...). Straight up repost from last year.

Comment: Composited in Powerpoint 2010 using a stock NIST logo.

Comment: This was my favorite ad. I like the CCCBDB geometry database for molecules. I think there isn't one for materials. The question "Is there a database where we can find previously determined geometries of materials?" got the highest score (+14) on my proposal to make this new stack exchange for materials science: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=YTIzYzdlMzg3OWQ1ZmQ5N2IwNTRkOGQ1MGIxYzkzMTkyNGRiNDA4NWI3NTllNzk2ZjU5MGJlNDI1NzMwZjVjOU1TH_a-r5fwqMIKGkGy_v3rn9gqkFujahQb0cy-OnFN0. Do you think you can help us launch this site by committing to it?

Answer (score 8):

[image: Visit our meta site!]

Comment: [Mandatory repost](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3549/4945)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Let's do the bounty dance! Enter your favourite question today!]

Comment: I would really love to revitalise this.

Comment: This link redirects to a meta post from 2015. 3 yeas later, I just wish to ask if the concept of bounty dance is still applicable? Essentially, how do you plan to "revitalize" this bounty dance, apart from posting this ad? Considering the fact there is no new activity in 2018 on that post at all. Though, do note that, and more importantly, this ad crossed the +6 votes ad display threshold on Feb 28, so it's been only a fortnight since it has been displaying. Yet, there hasn't been any new activity on that page. I think this is a nice idea to ponder upon whilst your intercontinental voyage ;)

Answer (score 8):

[image: AIST Spectral Database for Organic Compounds]

Comment: Repost from last year, though I'll be changing the spectrum to something else here soon.  Thinking the TNT mass spectrum....

Comment: Composited in Powerpoint 2010/2013 using a theme inspired by the site.

Comment: if you re-compose, I'd suggest maybe including the chemical structure near the spectrum?

Comment: Ahh, good idea, @GeoffHutchison. Should've done that for all of them!

Answer (score 7):

[image: eMolecules Substructure Search]

Comment: Debated a bit about this one since I suspect eMolecules supports itself by click-through sales at their listed vendors, but the substructure search is ***soooo helpful***, and the site navigation is decent.  Composited in Powerpoint 2013 from graphics drawn from the website.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Retraction Watch]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Click here to learn how to format chemical compounds and reaction mechanisms]

Comment: Reposted from last year

Answer (score 5):

[image: Avogadro - the open molecular editor]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Detexify: automated LaTeX symbol recognition]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting